# calling main method from another method in the same class

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

How to call the main method?

```
void prompt()
{
    System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
    Scanner confirm = new Scanner(System.in);
String con = confirm.nextLine();
if (con  == "y")
{
//call the main method once again.
}
}
```

When I use
    main();
    It asks for the value of "args" yet I'm not sure what value I should put in it.

Comment: Why you want to call the `main` method? Instead have the required functionality in a method and call it. It is really bad practice to have `main` doing lot of computations

Comment: In a word -- don't! That smells of a very bad design. You're better off writing a logical program that makes sense and doesn't have this weird and bad smelling requirement. Why not use a while loop instead? Also, don't compare Strings with `==`. Use the `equals(...)` method instead.

Comment: `Class.main(args); Class.main(new String[]{});` This is how. Now follow Prateek advice..

Comment: @porfiriopartida: now you will have to help him when he comes back with his recursive stackoverflow exception.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Don't worry, `con  == "y"` will never be true.. oooh but you told him how to pass that condition.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I will just transfer the codes to another method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Pleae check my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `main()` method in a java program takes a String array argument.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {}
```

If you do not use the variable `args` inside of main() you could just pass null to it.  Otherwise you would need to pass a String array to the method.

However, you should not be calling the `main()` method from inside your application.  The `main()` method should be used as an entry point into your application, to launch a program, not be used to recursively execute the logic inside that application.  If you have functionality needed again you should put it in a separate method.

Answer (score 0):

Signature of `main` method is: `public static void main(String[] args)`

The main method accepts a single argument: an array of elements of type String.

public static void main(`String[] args`)

This array is the mechanism through which the runtime system passes information to your application. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.out.println("args = " + args);
}

public static void prompt() {        
    System.out.println("Do you want to continue?");
    Scanner confirm = new Scanner(System.in);
    String con = confirm.nextLine();
    if (con  == "y") {

      String[] args = {<set string array>};
      main(args);

    }

}
```

For more details, look at this Oracle document: [The main Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html#MAIN)